# Is there a method of converting a form to json that do not generate duplicate values for checkboxes when checked?

Tags: jquery, json

Trying to convert a form to json

JSON.stringify($('#editGroupForm').serializeArray())

The problem is that checkboxes, when checked, gets two values, one with true and one with false. This of course reslut in problem when trying to receive on server.

Is there a method of converting a form to json that do not generate duplicate values for checkboxes when checked?

Comment: I'll go ahead and guess it's not the checkboxes by themselves that generate duplicates. There are hidden fields in your form responsible for the false values. Right?

Comment: Dude, post HTML, JS, goes a long way

Comment: there is one hidden field but not with the same id as the checkbox. when the checkbox is not checked only one value, false, is generated.

Comment: Jon, a Little closer look at the html i found that MVC:s @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Paid) generated a hidden. I tried replace this with <input type="checkbox" name="Paid" id="Paid" @((@Model.Paid == true) ? "checked" : "") /> but then when unchecked Paid was not included at all in the json, and when checked it gets "on" as value, not true as i want.

Comment: @MikeAlike234: What is your *actual* problem? Duplicate values by themselves are not a problem.

Comment: The problem is if I make a json with both a true and a false value for a checkbox, the modelbinder (serverside) will assign false no matter if checkbox is checked or not. Could you explain what you mean?